# Handling errors in $requireAuth with ui-router in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I've got an authenticated app and I'm trying to handle the unauthorized re-direct state for when the app first loads. I'm noticing in the debug console, that the app tires multiple times to handle an unauthorized loop, unsuccessfully about 5 or 6 times before it finally redirects to the login page I wanted it to. Can someone please help me figure out where I need to handle this error properly? Thanks.

My app.js file is:

```
    // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving
// Angular modules 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also
// set in a <body> attribute in index.html) the 2nd parameter is an array of 
// 'requires'.'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', 
  ['ionic', 'starter.constants', 'starter.services', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $ionicLoading) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory
    // bar above the keyboard for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
  // and redirect the user back to the home page
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $state.go('app.login');
      //console.log("This isn't working the way I want it to.");
      //login();
    } 
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.search', {
    url: '/app/search',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.browse', {
    url: '/browse',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.list', {
    url: '/list',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl',
        resolve:{
          full_list: function(ListService){
            return ListService.listAll();
          },
          current_Auth: function(LoginService){
            return LoginService.getAuthObject().$requireAuth();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.detail', {
    url: '/list/:itemId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl',
        resolve:{
          list_item: function($stateParams, ListService){
            return ListService.itemDetail($stateParams.itemId);
          },
          current_Auth: function(LoginService){
            return LoginService.getAuthObject().$requireAuth();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/list');
});
```

My controllers.js file is as follows:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $state, LoginService) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});
  $scope.userLoggedIn= LoginService.getAuthObject().$getAuth();

  $scope.logout=function(){
    $state.go('app.login');
    LoginService.getAuthObject().$unauth();
  }
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($state, $scope, $timeout, LoginService){
  $scope.loginData={};

  $scope.doLogin = function(){
    LoginService.authenticateUser($scope.loginData, 
      function(err, authData){
        if (err){
          console.log("Login failed!");
          return;
        }
        //$location.path('/app/list');
        $state.go('app.list');
      });
  };

  $scope.logout = function(){
    $state.go('app.login');
    LoginService.getAuthObject().$unauth();
    // $state.go('app.login');
  };
})

.controller('ListCtrl', function($state, $scope, full_list, current_Auth) {
  $scope.list = full_list;

  $scope.goToAccount=function(){
    $state.go('app.login');
  };
})

.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $state, list_item, current_Auth) {
  $scope.item = list_item;

  $scope.goToAccount=function(){
    $state.go('app.login');
  };
});
```

My services.js is as follows:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['firebase'])

.factory('LoginService', function($firebaseAuth){

    var ref = new Firebase('https://db-hidden-here.firebaseIO.com');

    return {
        authenticateUser: function (user, cb) {
            return ref.authWithPassword({
                email: user.username,
                password: user.password
                }, function(error, authData) {
                if (error) {
                    //Login failed
                    cb(error);
                } else {
                    cb(null, authData);
                }
            });
        },

        getAuthObject: function(){
            return $firebaseAuth(ref);
        }        
    };
})

.factory('ListService', function($q, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {

    var refList = 
    new Firebase('https://db-hidden-here.firebaseIO.com/coupons');

    return {
        listAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var items = $firebaseArray(refList);
            deferred.resolve(items);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        itemDetail: function(key) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var itemRef = refList.child(key);
            var item = $firebaseObject(itemRef);
            deferred.resolve(item);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

This is my debug output:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8900
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24553)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24783)
    at bootstrapApply (ionic.bundle.js:10465)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:13282)
    at doBootstrap (ionic.bundle.js:10463)
    at bootstrap (ionic.bundle.js:10483)
    at angularInit (ionic.bundle.js:10377)
    at ionic.bundle.js:37191
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (ionic.bundle.js:11828)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21162(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17941Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24785bootstrapApply @ ionic.bundle.js:10465invoke @ ionic.bundle.js:13282doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10463bootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10483angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:10377(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:37191trigger @ ionic.bundle.js:11828eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:12103
ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:8900Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:24553Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24783bootstrapApply @ ionic.bundle.js:10465invoke @ ionic.bundle.js:13282doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10463bootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10483angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:10377(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:37191trigger @ ionic.bundle.js:11828eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:12103
ionic.bundle.js:21162 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8900
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24553)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24783)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:19196)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19368)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:19309)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21162(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17941Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24785done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:8900Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:24553Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24783done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:21162 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8900
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24553)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24783)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:19196)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19368)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:19309)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21162(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17941Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24785done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:8900Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:24553Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24783done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:21162 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8900
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24553)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24783)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:19196)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19368)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:19309)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21162(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17941Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24785done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:8900Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:24553Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24783done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:21162 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8900
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24553)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24783)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:19196)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19368)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:19309)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21162(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17941Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24785done @ ionic.bundle.js:19196completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19368requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19309
ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

Please help me find out where I need to handle this error loop and how best to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is more to it but in your `$stateChangeError` you have to `event.preventDefault();` before `$state.go('app.login')` so that you prevent the `$UrlRouter` reverting the URL to the previous valid location

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
    // and redirect the user back to the home page
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('app.login');
      //console.log("This isn't working the way I want it to.");
      //login();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Gee...thanks!! Lmao! You're a life saver! I worked flawlessly lmao! Much appreciated sir.

Comment: no problem. this is actually is on the docs of `ui-router` but it's somewhat hard to find, bringing headaches to lots of people